# Dynamatically changing ticker text in Android without affecting the scroll position

Tags: android, scroll, marquee, ticker

I am trying to implement a Scrolling Text in my android App. I have used the following properties in my textview :

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:lines="1"
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

I am converting an array of Strings to a String object and setting it in the TextView. The problem is whenever I set a new String it scrolls back to the start. I want to add or remove items from the ticker without changing the scroll position.